# Rails app loading dozens of jquery assets

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, heroku, memory-leaks

My rails app generates an html page that includes about 40 links and 80 scripts in the head.  This can't be normal, can it?  I wonder if I can reduce those, if it might help with the memory errors that my app is throwing on heroku.  Or if it can help my app's performance speed.

**Compiled html** (I'll only include the first four link tags and the first four script tags, unless I get a request to post them all.)

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Dr. Macejkovic | Mr. Z School </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/theme.self-830c3407ba1359ea36eee978235be14de5b78dacfa658a31226fe4f2b0faa7e7.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/core.self-e4bdefd3813c8a715955a6c65b9e730846dcae6a0576618563d635ff0b18a3ca.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/accordion.self-aa0730fc025317fed4feff2aa5fc07cba5a545dfc5c913a2984ba6f8695b29fb.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/autocomplete.self-f0b810a4a7bb8c90994675d7c5bfe636d615a5785cf81cae3340aa5e6adc55ca.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />

#40 additional similar link tags omitted

  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="lQ2XTs3tTFNf+nuVR2NS9FPk/R4JWOO75SVBJuxfok547SCaN2KooB44hVwjJo1Pl5oX+bahrG8OdUyow5u6eQ==" />
   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/r29/html5.min.js">
      </script>
 <![endif]-->
  <script src="/assets/jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-e87806d0cf4489aeb1bb7288016024e8de67fd18db693fe026fe3907581e53cd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.self-d0e973a52d36a01036265aeefaf2d1ae3499d2cb231a9be3bd846432daf231de.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.turbolinks.self-176b9819f30444d441e820bbccd3264fe57753aeafd54dec732b0dbc77129a2a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>

  #80 additional similar script tags omitted
</head>
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',          '5.0.0'
gem 'bcrypt',         '3.1.11'
gem 'faker',          '1.6.3'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.1.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.6'
gem 'puma',           '3.4.0'
gem 'sass-rails',     '5.0.5'
gem 'uglifier',       '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails',   '4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails',   '4.1.1'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'turbolinks',     '5.0.0'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder',       '2.4.1'
gem 'best_in_place', '~> 3.1'
gem 'responders', '~> 2.2'
gem 'carrierwave', '0.11.2'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.3'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'fog-aws', '0.12.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.11'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.0', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.1.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.0.8'
  gem 'spring',                '1.7.1'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '0.1.1'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.9'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'poltergeist', '~> 1.10'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
end
```

**App/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %> </title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
</head>
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

  <div class="container">
    <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
        <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %>
    <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance for any insight.

P.S.  This question is only one of the steps that I'm trying in my quest to resolve the memory errors.  If you have some clear advice or some recommended articles, I would be grateful for those too.  I'm working my way through this article http://www.schneems.com/2015/05/11/how-ruby-uses-memory.html, but I'm struggling to figure out how to apply this info to my app.

Comment: When you say memory errors on heroku, what do you mean exactly?  Depending on what you are using for frontend management, those 4 links seem pretty standard for many rails projects using bootstrap css (jquery, jquery ujs, turbolinks and bootstrap).  You would get a rendering boost by putting all of those in the end of your html body but that can cause issues if all of your plugins aren't written in a way to support that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The specific error in the tail log reads "R14 Memory Quota exceeded in Ruby".  It is causing my users to see an "Application Error" dead page. Those four links are only a sample. I've omitted the majority to keep this question manageable.  There are about 40 link tags and 80 script tags in the full html head. I have tried linking to the jquery in the end, but that caused most of it to stop working.

Comment: Ok, yeah the memory on the server is not going to be related to the ruby memory going high.  Those links are generated on the server but from a Ruby/Rails memory perspective they are essentially free b/c they do not download them or do anything, they merely tag them with an asset fingerprint and then inline them in your html.

Comment: Cool. Thanks.  So it sounds like it's not worth trimming those for the sake of memory. Is it possibly worth trying trim them for faster page loads?

Comment: Yes, but that is dependent on the frontend javascripts ability to handle those things being loaded at the end of the page after everything on the html is painted.

Answer (score 0):

The above additional js files loading through the gems

```
gem 'jquery-rails',   '4.1.1'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'turbolinks',     '5.0.0'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

When you have included those gems in gem file, the js files will be added to the

```
app/assets/javascripts/application.js
```

For example:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

If you don't need those jquery and turbo links you can take an action on those gems.

For more information you can see those gems documentation.

for jquery:
   https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/jquery-rails/4.3.3

Comment: Does this mean that everybody who uses these four gems also finds over 100 js tags in their html? So there's no way to pare down some of them without removing gems?

Comment: @JeffZivkovic I am giving the example using some gems will include some javascript links, the same rule will not  applicable for all gems.